# Unable to access file in home directory (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a simple Jupyter Notebook [here](http://jupyter.org/try). In my code I have to load a file `file.txt` placed in `/data` directory in home

```
data/file.txt
```

Code

```
open('data/file.txt', 'r')
```

or

```
open('~/data/file.txt', 'r')
```

I am getting an error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/data/file.txt'

Comment: @snakecharmerb how can i get `myusername`. I tried getting username from url but it's not working. `https://hub.mybinder.org/user/ipython-ipython-in-depth-xxxx/notebooks/binder/Index.ipynb#`. Path `/home/ipython-ipython-in-depth-xxxx/data/file.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access your home directory using the [os.path.expanduser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) function to get the name of the home directory.

```
import os
import os.path

# Create data directory
try:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'data'))
except OSError:
    pass

# Write to file
with open(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'data/file.txt'), 'w') as f:
    f.write('Hello world')

# Read from file    
with open(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'data/file.txt')) as f:
    print(f.read())

Hello world
```

Comment: I noticed that `Index.ipynb` was in `binder` directory, So I moved the `data` directory inside the `binder` directory and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Jupyter notebooks always run on the directory where the notebook was started, by default, so you should reference the file by it's relative path (`./`)

Eg. This works:

```
with open('./data/file.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line.strip())
```

So, using `./<any_dirpath>/<file>` works on a local jupyter installation.

If you are using binder or any remote site, the home directory is not your local dir, but the remote dir instead, so unless you upload the file you're working with, you wont be able to read it.

You can check the current dir by running:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd() + "\n")
```

Comment: Im a bit confused - shouldnt ~/ give you your home path regardless of what pwd you're in?  I have this same issue on MacOS running Jupyter notebook where /Users/me/<filename> is accessible but ~/filename does not.

Comment: @user391339 It's not a Jupyter issue. As per [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), Python needs a relative or absolute file path, and it does not expand tilde ~ into the absolute path of the user's home.

For that, you should use:
`import os` and then  `os.path.expanduser('~')`